# input :checked & toggle() in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

In my jquery i have the following code, which for some reason is not working as i expected. On testing the code doesn't perform the css changes.  If i remove the :checked and just have $("input") then the css works but only on the clicking of a input:checkbox

```
$("input :checked").toggle(function() {
    // Stuff to do every *odd* time the element is clicked;
    $(this).siblings('a').css("text-decoration","line-through");
    $(this).siblings('a').css("color","#aaa");
    $(this).parent('li').css("background-color","#ccc");
}, function() {
    // Stuff to do every *even* time the element is clicked;
    $(this).siblings('a').css("text-decoration","none");
    $(this).siblings('a').css("color","");
    $(this).parent('li').css("background-color","");
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you post your markup?

Comment: A simple todo style application

Comment: `<ul>
    <li  class="item selected"><input type="checkbox"/><a href="#">Get the €'s<span class="today">23</span></a></li>
   </ul>`

Comment: Ok, you say that without `:checked` this _works but only on the clicking of a input:checkbox_. How do you expect it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      // Stuff to do every *odd* time the element is clicked;
      $(this).siblings('a').css("text-decoration","line-through");
      $(this).siblings('a').css("color","#aaa");
      $(this).parent('li').css("background-color","#ccc");
    } 
    else {
      // Stuff to do every *even* time the element is clicked;
      $(this).siblings('a').css("text-decoration","none");
      $(this).siblings('a').css("color","");
      $(this).parent('li').css("background-color","");
    }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/AwMf3/

Comment: It does work, but is a bit excessive.  Using the suggestion from @Karolis, changing your original code from `$("input :checked")` to `$("input:checkbox")` will work as well, removing the need for the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

Input elements can't have descendants. Maybe you mean `input:checked` (without space)?